# O que chamar a uma refeição a meio da manhã?

Tags: vocabulário

Brunch (além de estrangeirismo) é para quem não toma pequeno-almoço e junta a refeição com o almoço.

Lanche é a meio da tarde.

O que chamar a uma refeição feita a meio da manhã, entre o pequeno-almoço e o almoço?

Comment: Lanche da manhã? Acredito que o *pequeno-almoço* é o café da manhã ou desjejum...

Comment: Eu diria lanche também... não me parece que o termo seja específico a um período do dia em particular.

Comment: Para mim, é o "segundo café"...

Comment: Lanche pode ser a qualquer horário...

Comment: Existe o café da tarde. Na maioria dos lugares que visitei, acordávamos comendo café da manhã, então, almoço, então, café da tarde, então, jantar.

Answer (score 5):

Nenhuma das sugestões abaixo é específica para o horário da manhã, mas todas podem ser usadas. Dependendo de onde estejas e com quem estejas, tu poderás ouvir:

- Sempre faço **uma merenda** entre as duas etapas da manhã.
- Ainda são 10 horas e já estou com fome. Vou **forrar o estômago**.
- Eu sempre faço **uma boquinha** no meio da manhã.
- Eu sei que vamos almoçar na casa da tua mãe. Tô só fazendo **um lanchinho**.

Referências:

[**1- fazer uma boquinha**](http://www.dicionarioinformal.com.br/fazer+uma+boquinha/)

[**2- merenda**](http://www.dicionarioinformal.com.br/merenda/)

[**3- forrar o estômago**](http://www.aulete.com.br/est%C3%B4mago)

[**4- lanchinho**](http://www.dicionarioinformal.com.br/lanchinho/)

Comment: eu uso merenda normalmente algo que acontece no colégio. Pode ser de manhã ou de tarde, dependendo do turno.

Answer (score 4):

**Lanche**. Pelo menos pt-BR *lanche* não é restrito ao período da tarde, como registra o [Michaelis](http://michaelis.uol.com.br/moderno-portugues/busca/portugues-brasileiro/lanche/):

> Refeição ligeira a qualquer hora

Answer (score 3):

Em Portugal (vá, no meu meio social em Lisboa), *lanche* refere-se sempre a uma refeição a meio da tarde, lá por volta das 5 da tarde. Quando se fala em «hora do lanche», ninguém vai pensar em outra hora que não essa.

A palavra *merenda* parece-me ligeiramente mais plausível. Mas *merenda* é geralmente usada com o sentido de *farnel* (ex.: *às 14h, a jovem comitiva parou para tirar a merenda da mochila*, *levar/trazer merenda*). No exemplos que encontrei em que a palavra se usava no sentido de refeição e se podia inferir a hora do dia, era sempre uma refeição a meio da tarde. De resto, a palavra *merenda* tem, em certos meios, uma carga negativa (as pessoas "sofisticadas" não levam merenda ou farnel de casa, simplesmente levam comida de casa):

> Por inabilidade das relações públicas da Parque Expo ou por exagero interpretativo dos jornalistas, a verdade é que a palavra «merenda» se tornou subitamente imprópria, com uma carga pejorativa que a todos causa repugnância (e assim, por arrastamento, corremos o risco de ver os piqueniques serem substituídos por «momentos de fruição da natureza» e os bolinhos de bacalhau por «um `snack' ligeiro para conforto do estômago»).

A verdade é que, tanto quanto saiba, não há qualquer palavra específica para essa refeição. Dizemos simplesmente *leva uma peça de fruta para comeres a meio da manhã* ou *alguém quer ir ao café?* (enquanto à tarde se poderia dizer *quem quer vir lanchar?*).

Comment: Há ainda o comentário machista, usado cá por estas bandas: "quem é aquela?"  "Ah, é uma [**merenda antiga**](http://www.arnaldotemporal.com.br/raiz/humor/cafajeste.html)".

Answer (score 0):

Primeiro-cartel era a paragem para comer a meio da manhã na minha região gandaresa.

Comment: Boas-vindas ao Portuguese SE! Obrigado pela contribuição, mas por favor note que geralmente se esperam respostas bem fundamentadas — por exemplo com referências. Não encontro nenhuma referência à expressão "primeiro-cartel", você poderia incluir uma fonte?

Comment: Será que seria "primeiro [farnel](https://www.infopedia.pt/dicionarios/lingua-portuguesa/farnel)"? Mas também não encontro referências.